# C# mirror of SQL Server's CHECKSUM()

Tags: c#, sql-server

What code in c# produces identical results to [`CHECKSUM()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) in TSQL?

I was able to port [`BINARY_CHECKSUM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784.aspx) to c# using this [link](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=70832).

Is there similar way to port `CHECKSUM()` too?

---

For example, the TSQL

```
SELECT CHECKSUM('12')
```

outputs,

```
2262
```

What c# code would produce the same result, for this example and all other possible inputs?

Comment: check the following link:  [Calculate MD5 checksum for a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520048/calculate-md5-checksum-for-a-file)

Comment: Do you mean "equivalent" as "performs the same job" or "given the same input data, both the C# code and CHECKSUM will produce identical outputs"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , by "equivalent" i meant should produce identical output.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877523/sqlserver-checksum-in-c-sharp

Comment: @JitendraRathor I've edited your question to match your comments. Now, this question is an exact duplicate. Please don't ask duplicates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877523/sqlserver-checksum-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

[`HASHBYTES()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx)

Returns the MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA, SHA1, or SHA2 hash of its input in SQL Server.

Comment: are you suggesting `HASHBYTES` as an alternative to `CHECKSUM` that can be easily mirrored in c#? What c# code would do that?

Comment: I agree except that HASHBYTES has an 8000 byte limit in older versions of Sql Server and CHECKSUM doesn't.