# SSMS: Automatically save multiple result sets from same SQL script into separate tabs in Excel?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssms, export-to-csv

I have a SQL query I'm running in SSMS that generates about 8 different resulting datasets (all with different columns). Is there a way to have each of the result sets get out output to a separate tab in Excel without having to copy/paste and result set table individually from SSMS.

I know one approach would be to UNION all the results and patch with fake columns (so that the columns line up) and then generate a single output set. But that would then require manually filtering and separating the result set. Is there a quicker/easier/other way to do this? Worst case I can deal with a single output that I need to filter but eventually this query will be updated to generate up to ~ 40 result sets on each run so it would be very tedious to have to manually separate that afterwards.

Comment: A SQL query can only generate one dataset, not many. I *assume* you mean you have a batch with multiple queries. If so, no, there is no magic "export all dataset into Excel on different worksheet" button. There may be in an installable add-on/extension but not one I know and [so] isn't the place for software recommendations.

Comment: You are right, I do mean a SQL script or batch of queries.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it but you might be able to send your queries from Excel. I would use R or Python to connect to SQL Server and execute my queries from there and then use R or Python functions to export the data frames to Excel. But I am sure there are easier ways and I would do like that because I know how to use these tools...

Try this [Export SQL query data to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389637/export-sql-query-data-to-excel)

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to allow Ole Automation Procedures you can use this solution as below. You could also create a stored procedure that does not use the @OutputFileName parameter and use bcp to save the binary content to a file (using a format file that exports binary content without adding data to the beginning of the output).

I wrote this out of frustration for not being able to easily generate Excel Spreadsheets with text or number formatting that I required. Procedure AddFileToArchive generates a zip archive containing the contents of an input file and is used internally by GetExcelSpreadsheetData.

GetExcelSpreadsheetData generates a worksheet for one or more temporary tables and outputs a compliant open xml workbook. Worksheets have column headings in bold font. If you output the file with a .zip extension you will see the internal file contents similar to any other .xlsx file, however the data is internally stored inline instead of in shared values. Worksheets can be autofiltered by adding the "autofilter" option.

Date formatting is currently hard coded to dd/mm/yyyy however you can change that by altering these lines:

```
    <numFmt formatCode="dd/mm/yyyy\ hh:mm" numFmtId="165"/>
    <numFmt formatCode="hh:mm" numFmtId="166"/>
    <numFmt formatCode="dd/mm/yyyy" numFmtId="167"/>
```

Sorry about the lack of comments.

Credit to [Does SQL Server CheckSum calculate a CRC? If not how can I get MS SQL to calculate a CRC on an arbitrary varchar column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331157) for the GetCRC32 code used if executed on SQL Server 2012 or 2014.

Example usage at the bottom.

Hopefully you will find this useful. This procedure does not work on SQL Server 2008R2 or earlier.

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[GetCRC32]    Script Date: 23/10/2020 4:52:31 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create function [dbo].[GetCRC32](@Text varchar(max)) returns binary(4) as
begin
    declare
        @crc bigint = 0xFFFFFFFF
        ,@Lookup varbinary(2048) = 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
        ,@LenText int = len(@Text);
 
        with x as (
            select '' as Id
            union all
            select '' as Id from x
        )
        ,y as (select top (cast(ceiling(sqrt(sqrt(@LenText))) as int)) '' as id from x)
        ,v as (
            select top (@LenText) row_number() over (order by (select null)) as ID
            from y cross join y as y2 cross join y as y3 cross join y as y4
        )
    SELECT @crc = (@crc / 256) ^ Substring(@Lookup, ((@crc & 0xFF) ^ Ascii(Substring(@Text, V.ID, 1))) * 4 + 1, 4)
    FROM  V
 
    SET @crc = ~@crc;
 
    return cast(reverse(cast(@crc as varbinary(4))) as binary(4));
end
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[StringSplit2]    Script Date: 23/10/2020 4:52:32 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create function [dbo].[StringSplit2] (@StringToSplit varchar(max), @Seperator char(1)) returns table
as
return (
    with Split as (
        select
            1 as ValueOrder
            ,cast(1 as int) as ValueStartPos
            ,cast(charindex(@Seperator, @StringToSplit + @Seperator) as int) as ValueEndPos
        union all
        select
            ValueOrder + 1 as ValueOrder
            ,ValueEndPos + 1 as ValueStartPos
            ,cast(charindex(@Seperator, @StringToSplit + @Seperator, ValueEndPos + 1) as int) as ValueEndPos
        from Split
        where ValueEndPos <> 0
    )
    select
        ValueOrder
        ,substring(@StringToSplit, ValueStartPos, case when ValueEndPos = 0 then 0 else ValueEndPos-ValueStartPos end) as value
    from Split
    where ValueEndPos <> 0
)
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[AddFileToArchive]    Script Date: 23/10/2020 4:52:32 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create procedure [dbo].[AddFileToArchive](@FileName varchar(max), @FileContents varbinary(max), @ArchiveData varbinary(max) output, @ArchiveInfo binary(10) output)
as
begin
    set nocount on;
 
    declare
        @LocalFileHeaderSignature binary(4) = 0x504b0304
        ,@CentralDirectoryFileHeaderSignature binary(4) = 0x504b0102
        ,@EndOfCentralDirectorySignature binary(4) = 0x504b0506
        ,@VersionNeededToExtract binary(2) = 0x1400
        ,@VersionMadeBy binary(2) = 0x1400
        ,@GeneralPurposeBitFlag binary(2) = 0x0000
        ,@CompressionMethod binary(2) = 0x0000--0x0800
        ,@CompressionMethodDeflate binary(2) = 0x0800
        ,@FileLastModificationTime binary(2) = 0xA351 -- dummy time
        ,@FileLastModificationDate binary(2) = 0x6250 -- dummy date
        ,@currentDateTime datetime = getdate()
        ,@CRC32 binary(4)
        ,@CompressedSize int
        ,@UncompressedSize int
        ,@FileNameLength smallint
        ,@ExtraFieldLength smallint = 0
        ,@FileCommentLength smallint = 0
        ,@CommentLength smallint = 0
        ,@NumberOfThisDisk smallint = 0
        ,@DiskNumberWhereFileStarts smallint = 0
        ,@InternalFileAttributes binary(2) = 0x0100
        ,@ExternalFileAttributes binary(4) = 0x20000000
        ,@LocalFileRecordLength int
 
        ,@LocalFileRecord varbinary(max)
        ,@CompressedFileContents varbinary(max)
        ,@LenCompressedFileContents int
        ,@FileCRC32 binary(4)
        ,@OffsetOfStartOfCentralDirectory int
 
        ,@CentralDirectoryRecord varbinary(max)
        ,@EndOfCentralDirectoryRecord varbinary(max)
                   
        ,@sql nvarchar(max)
        ,@OtherFileCount smallint
        ,@FileOffset int
        ,@SizeOfCentralDirectory int;
 
    set @OtherFileCount = IsNull(cast(SubString(@ArchiveInfo, 1, 2) as smallint), 0);
    set @FileOffset = IsNull(cast(SubString(@ArchiveInfo, 3, 4) as int), 0);
    set @SizeOfCentralDirectory = IsNull(cast(SubString(@ArchiveInfo, 7, 4) as int), 0);
 
    set @FileLastModificationTime = cast(reverse(cast((datepart(ss, @currentDateTime) / 2) | (32 * datepart(mi, @currentDateTime)) | (2048 * datepart(hh, @currentDateTime)) as binary(2))) as binary (2));
    set @FileLastModificationDate = cast(reverse(cast((datepart(dd, @currentDateTime)) | (32 * datepart(mm, @currentDateTime)) | (512 * (datepart(yy, @currentDateTime) - 1980)) as binary(2))) as binary (2));
 
    -- for SQL Server 2016 or higher compress the file contents
    if cast(serverproperty('ProductMajorVersion') as int) > 12 -- SQL Server 2016+
    begin
        exec sp_executesql
            @stmt = N'set @CompressedFileContents = compress(@FileContents)'
            ,@params = N'@FileContents varbinary(max), @CompressedFileContents varbinary(max) output'
            ,@CompressedFileContents = @CompressedFileContents output
            ,@FileContents = @FileContents;
        set @FileCRC32 = substring(@CompressedFileContents, len(@CompressedFileContents) - 7, 4);
        set @CompressionMethod = @CompressionMethodDeflate;
    end
    else
    begin
        set @CompressedFileContents = 0x00000000000000000000 + @FileContents + 0x0000000000000000;
        exec sp_executesql
            @stmt = N'set @FileCRC32 = dbo.GetCRC32(@FileContents)'
            ,@params = N'@FileContents varbinary(max), @FileCRC32 binary(4) output'
            ,@FileContents = @FileContents
            ,@FileCRC32 = @FileCRC32 output;
    end;
 
    set @LenCompressedFileContents = len(@CompressedFileContents);
    set @CompressedSize = @LenCompressedFileContents - 18;
    set @UncompressedSize = len(@FileContents);
 
    set @FileNameLength = len(@FileName);
 
    set @LocalFileRecord =
        @LocalFileHeaderSignature
        +@VersionNeededToExtract
        +@GeneralPurposeBitFlag
        +@CompressionMethod
        +@FileLastModificationTime
        +@FileLastModificationDate
        +@FileCRC32
        +cast(reverse(cast(@CompressedSize as binary(4))) as binary(4))
        +cast(reverse(cast(@UncompressedSize as binary(4))) as binary(4))
        +cast(reverse(cast(@FileNameLength as binary(2))) as binary(2))
        +cast(reverse(cast(@ExtraFieldLength as binary(2))) as binary(2))
        +cast(@FileName as varbinary(max))
        +substring(@CompressedFileContents, 11, @LenCompressedFileContents - 18);
 
    set @CentralDirectoryRecord =
        @CentralDirectoryFileHeaderSignature
        +@VersionMadeBy
        +@VersionNeededToExtract
        +@GeneralPurposeBitFlag
        +@CompressionMethod
        +@FileLastModificationTime
        +@FileLastModificationDate
        +@FileCRC32
        +cast(reverse(cast(@CompressedSize as binary(4))) as binary(4))
        +cast(reverse(cast(@UncompressedSize as binary(4))) as binary(4))
        +cast(reverse(cast(@FileNameLength as binary(2))) as binary(2))
        +cast(reverse(cast(@ExtraFieldLength as binary(2))) as binary(2))
        +cast(reverse(cast(@FileCommentLength as binary(2))) as binary(2))
        +cast(reverse(cast(@DiskNumberWhereFileStarts as binary(2))) as binary(2))
        +@InternalFileAttributes
        +@ExternalFileAttributes
        +cast(reverse(cast(@FileOffset as binary(4))) as binary(4))
        +cast(@FileName as varbinary(max));
 
    set @SizeOfCentralDirectory = @SizeOfCentralDirectory + len(@CentralDirectoryRecord);
    set @LocalFileRecordLength= len(@LocalFileRecord)
    set @OffsetOfStartOfCentralDirectory = @FileOffset + @LocalFileRecordLength;
 
    set @EndOfCentralDirectoryRecord =
        @EndOfCentralDirectorySignature
        +cast(reverse(cast(@NumberOfThisDisk as binary(2))) as binary(2))
        +cast(reverse(cast(@NumberOfThisDisk as binary(2))) as binary(2)) -- Disk where central directory starts
        +cast(reverse(cast(@OtherFileCount + cast(1 as smallint) as binary(2))) as binary(2)) -- Number of central directory records on this disk
        +cast(reverse(cast(@OtherFileCount + cast(1 as smallint) as binary(2))) as binary(2)) -- Total number of central directory records
        +cast(reverse(cast(@SizeOfCentralDirectory as binary(4))) as binary(4))
        +cast(reverse(cast(@OffsetOfStartOfCentralDirectory as binary(4))) as binary(4))
        +cast(reverse(cast(@CommentLength as binary(2))) as binary(2))
 
    if @ArchiveInfo is null
        set @ArchiveData = @LocalFileRecord + @CentralDirectoryRecord + @EndOfCentralDirectoryRecord
    else
        set @ArchiveData =
            SubString(@ArchiveData, 1, @FileOffset) + @LocalFileRecord
            +SubString(@ArchiveData, @FileOffset + 1, @SizeOfCentralDirectory - len(@CentralDirectoryRecord)) + @CentralDirectoryRecord
            +@EndOfCentralDirectoryRecord;
 
    set @ArchiveInfo =
        cast(@OtherFileCount + 1 as binary(2))
        + cast(@FileOffset + @LocalFileRecordLength as binary(4))
        + cast(@SizeOfCentralDirectory as binary(4));
 
--             select @ArchiveInfo as ArchiveInfo, @LocalFileRecord as LocalFileRecord,@CentralDirectoryRecord as CentralDirectoryRecord, @EndOfCentralDirectoryRecord as EndOfCentralDirectoryRecord
    return;
end
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetExcelSpreadsheetData]    Script Date: 23/10/2020 4:52:32 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 
CREATE      procedure [dbo].[GetExcelSpreadsheetData](@SheetName varchar(31) = null, @Worksheets varchar(max) = null, @WorkbookData varbinary(max) = null output, @OutputFileName nvarchar(500) = null)
as
    set nocount on;
 
declare
    @LocalFileRecords varbinary(max)
    ,@CentralDirectoryRecords varbinary(max)
    ,@EndOfCentralDirectoryRecord varbinary(max)
    ,@OtherFileCount smallint
    ,@FileOffset int
    ,@SizeOfCentralDirectory int
    ,@NumberOfWorksheets smallint
    ,@CurrentWorksheet smallint = 1
    ,@sql nvarchar(max) = N''
    ,@rowcountsql nvarchar(max)
    ,@rowcount int
    ,@colcount int
    ,@datatable varchar(100)
    ,@RowDataXML nvarchar(max)
    ,@SelectOutput bit = 0
    ,@ArchiveInfo binary(10)
    ,@WorksheetFileName varchar(50)
    ,@ObjectToken int
    ,@AutoFilterXML nvarchar(max) = N''
 
    ,@_Content_Types__xml__sheets nvarchar(max)
    ,@_Content_Types__xml varbinary(max)
    ,@Workbook_xml_temp nvarchar(max)
    ,@Workbook_xml varbinary(max)
    ,@_Rels_workbook_xml_rels varbinary(max)
    ,@styles_xml varbinary(max) = cast(N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<styleSheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <numFmts count="3">
    <numFmt formatCode="dd/mm/yyyy\ hh:mm" numFmtId="165"/>
    <numFmt formatCode="hh:mm" numFmtId="166"/>
    <numFmt formatCode="dd/mm/yyyy" numFmtId="167"/>
  </numFmts>
  <fonts count="7">
    <font>    <sz val="11"/>            <name val="Calibri"/><family val="2" /><scheme val="minor" /></font>
    <font>    <sz val="11"/><color rgb="FFFF0000" /><name val="Calibri"/><family val="2" /><scheme val="minor" /></font>
    <font><b/><sz val="11"/>            <name val="Calibri"/><family val="2" /><scheme val="minor" /></font>
    <font><i/><sz val="11"/>            <name val="Calibri"/><family val="2" /><scheme val="minor" /></font>
    <font>    <sz val="11"/><color rgb="FF0070C0" /><name val="Calibri"/><family val="2" /><scheme val="minor" /></font>
    <font>    <sz val="20"/>            <name val="Calibri"/><family val="2" /><scheme val="minor" /></font>
    <font>    <sz val="11"/>            <name val="Courier"/><family val="3" />       </font>
  </fonts>
  <fills count="2">
    <fill>
      <patternFill patternType="none" />
    </fill>
    <fill>
      <patternFill patternType="gray125" />
    </fill>
  </fills>
  <borders count="1">
    <border>
      <left />
      <right />
      <top />
      <bottom />
      <diagonal />
    </border>
  </borders>
  <cellStyleXfs count="1">
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" />
  </cellStyleXfs>
  <cellXfs count="10">
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" />
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="2" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" />
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="3" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" />
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="4" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" />
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="1" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" />
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="5" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" />
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="6" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1" />
    <xf numFmtId="165" borderId="0" fillId="0" fontId="0" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1"/>
    <xf numFmtId="166" borderId="0" fillId="0" fontId="0" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1"/>
    <xf numFmtId="167" borderId="0" fillId="0" fontId="0" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1"/>
  </cellXfs>
  <cellStyles count="1">
    <cellStyle name="Standard" xfId="0" builtinId="0" />
  </cellStyles>
  <dxfs count="0" />
  <tableStyles count="0" defaultTableStyle="TableStyleMedium9" defaultPivotStyle="PivotStyleLight16" />
</styleSheet>' as varbinary(max))
 
    ,@worksheet_xml varbinary(max)
 
    ,@_rels_rels varbinary(max) = cast(N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
  <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="workbook.xml"/>
</Relationships>' as varbinary(max));
 
    -- if Worksheets is not specified, set @Worksheets to @SheetName + / + #data
    if @Worksheets is null-- @SheetName is not null and @Worksheets is null
        set @Worksheets = IsNull(@SheetName, 'Sheet1') + '/#data';
 
    -- if a non-null value is passed in @WorkbookData, the output should be set in the optional output parameter @WorkbookData
    -- if a null or no value is passed in @WorkbookData, the output will be selected at the end of the procedure
    if @WorkbookData is null and @OutputFileName is null
        set @SelectOutput = 1
    else
        set @WorkbookData = null;
 
    select
        Worksheet.ValueOrder as WorksheetNumber
        ,WorksheetTable.ValueOrder as ColumnNumber
        ,WorksheetTable.value
        ,WorksheetTableOptions.ValueOrder as WorksheetOptionNumber
        ,WorksheetTableOptions.value as WorksheetOption
    into #WorksheetConfig
    from dbo.StringSplit2(@Worksheets, '|') as Worksheet
    cross apply dbo.StringSplit2(Worksheet.value, '/') as WorksheetTable
    cross apply dbo.StringSplit2(WorksheetTable.value, '~') as WorksheetTableOptions;
 
    select
        @NumberOfWorksheets = max(WorksheetNumber)
    from #WorksheetConfig;
                   
    -- xml for @Workbook_xml
    with xmlnamespaces (
       'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships' as r
       ,default 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main'
    )
    select @Workbook_xml_temp = (
        select
            Worksheet.value as [sheet/@name]
            ,Worksheet.WorksheetNumber as [sheet/@sheetId]
            ,'rId' + cast(Worksheet.WorksheetNumber + 1 as varchar) as [sheet/@r:id]
        from #WorksheetConfig Worksheet
        where ColumnNumber = 1
        for xml path('sheets'), root('workbook')
    );
 
    set @Workbook_xml = cast(Replace(@Workbook_xml_temp, '</sheets><sheets>', '') as varbinary(max));
               
    -- xml for @_Content_Types__xml
    select @_Content_Types__xml__sheets = (
        select
            '/sheet' + cast(Worksheet.WorksheetNumber as varchar) + '.xml' as [@PartName]
            ,'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml' as [@ContentType]
        from #WorksheetConfig Worksheet
        where ColumnNumber = 1
        for xml path('Override')
    );
 
    -- xml for @_Rels_workbook_xml_rels
    with xmlnamespaces (
       default 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships'
    )
    ,x as (
        select
            'rId1' as [@Id]
            ,'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles' as [@Type]
            ,'styles.xml' as [@Target]
        union all
        select
            'rId' + cast(Worksheet.WorksheetNumber + 1 as varchar) as [@Id]
            ,'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet' as [@Type]
            ,'sheet' + cast(Worksheet.WorksheetNumber as varchar) + '.xml' as [@Target]
        from #WorksheetConfig Worksheet
        where ColumnNumber = 1
    )
    select @_Rels_workbook_xml_rels = cast((
        select
            *
        from x
        for xml path('Relationship'), root('Relationships')
    ) as varbinary(max));
 
    set @_Content_Types__xml = cast(N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
  <Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/workbook.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml"/>
' + @_Content_Types__xml__sheets + '
</Types>' as varbinary(max));
 
exec dbo.AddFileToArchive
    @FileName = '[Content_Types].xml'
    ,@FileContents = @_Content_Types__xml
    ,@ArchiveData = @WorkbookData output
    ,@ArchiveInfo = @ArchiveInfo output;
 
exec dbo.AddFileToArchive
    @FileName = '_rels/.rels'
    ,@FileContents = @_rels_rels
    ,@ArchiveData = @WorkbookData output
    ,@ArchiveInfo = @ArchiveInfo output;
 
exec dbo.AddFileToArchive
    @FileName = '_rels/workbook.xml.rels'
    ,@FileContents = @_Rels_workbook_xml_rels
    ,@ArchiveData = @WorkbookData output
    ,@ArchiveInfo = @ArchiveInfo output;
 
exec dbo.AddFileToArchive
    @FileName = 'workbook.xml'
    ,@FileContents = @workbook_xml
    ,@ArchiveData = @WorkbookData output
    ,@ArchiveInfo = @ArchiveInfo output;
 
exec dbo.AddFileToArchive
    @FileName = 'styles.xml'
    ,@FileContents = @styles_xml
    ,@ArchiveData = @WorkbookData output
    ,@ArchiveInfo = @ArchiveInfo output;
 
while @CurrentWorksheet <= @NumberOfWorksheets
begin
    set @sql = '';
 
    select
        @datatable = value
    from #WorksheetConfig
    where WorksheetNumber = @CurrentWorksheet
    and ColumnNumber = 2;
               
    select @sql +=
    ',''' + rtrim(case when column_id > 26 then char(64 + ((column_id -1) / 26)) + char(65 + ((column_id -1) % 26)) else char(64 + column_id) end) + ''' + cast(__r__ as varchar) as [c/@r]'
    + case when sc.system_type_id in (40, 41, 42, 43, 48, 52, 56, 58, 61, 62, 104, 106, 108, 127) then '' else ',''inlineStr'' as [c/@t]' end -- non text data types
    + case
        when sc.system_type_id in (42, 43, 58, 61) then ',7 as [c/@s]' -- datetime2, datetimeoffset smalldatetime, datetime
        when sc.system_type_id in (41) then ',8 as [c/@s]' -- time
        when sc.system_type_id in (40) then ',9 as [c/@s]' -- date
        else ''
    end -- smalldatetime, datetime, time, date
    + ',' + case
                when sc.system_type_id in (40, 58, 61) then 'cast(cast(' + quotename(name) + 'as datetime) as float) + case when ''19000301'' > ' + quotename(name) + ' then 1 else 2 end'
                when sc.system_type_id in (42, 43) then 'cast(cast(cast(' + quotename(name) + ' as date) as datetime) as float) + datepart(hh, ' + quotename(name) + ') / 24.00000 + datepart(mi, ' + quotename(name) + ') / 1440.00000 + datepart(ss, ' + quotename(name) + ') / 86400.00000 + datepart(ms, ' + quotename(name) + ') / 86400000.00000 + case when ''19000301'' > ' + quotename(name) + ' then 1 else 2 end'
                when sc.system_type_id in (41) then 'cast(cast(' + quotename(name) + ' as datetime) as float)' else quotename(name)
            end
    + case when sc.system_type_id in (40, 41, 42, 43, 48, 52, 56, 58, 61, 62, 104, 106, 108, 127) then ' as [c/v]' else ' as [c/is/t]' end
    + ','''''
    from tempdb.sys.columns sc
    where object_id = object_id('tempdb.dbo.' + @datatable)
    order by column_id;
 
    set @sql = right(@sql, len(@sql) - 1);
 
    set @sql =
    'select @xml = (select(cast((
            select
                1 as [@r]
                ,(
                    select
                        rtrim(case when column_id > 26 then char(64 + ((column_id -1) / 26)) + char(65 + ((column_id -1) % 26)) else char(64 + column_id) end) + ''1'' as [c/@r]
                        ,1 as [c/@s]
                        ,''inlineStr'' as [c/@t]
                        ,name as [c/is/t]
                    from tempdb.sys.columns sc
                    where object_id = object_id(''' + case when left(@datatable, 1) = '#' then 'tempdb.dbo.' else '' end + Replace(@datatable, '''', '''''') + ''')
                    order by column_id
                    for xml path(''''), type
                )
                from (select 1 as c1) x
                for xml path(''row''))
    as nvarchar(max))))
    +
    (select(IsNull(cast((
            select
                __r__ as [@r]
                ,(
                    select
    ' + @sql + '
                    for xml path(''''), type
                )
                from (select row_number() over (order by (select 1)) + 1 as __r__, * from ' + Replace(@datatable, '''', '''''') + ') d
                for xml path(''row''))
    as nvarchar(max)), '''')));';
 
    exec sp_executesql @stmt = @sql, @params = N'@xml nvarchar(max) output', @xml = @RowDataXML output;
 
    if exists (select * from #WorksheetConfig where WorksheetNumber = @CurrentWorksheet and ColumnNumber = 3 and WorksheetOption = 'autofilter')
    begin
        set @rowcountsql = N'select @rowcount = count(*) + 1 from ' + @datatable;
        exec sp_executesql @stmt = @rowcountsql, @params = N'@rowcount int output', @rowcount = @rowcount output;
 
        select
            @colcount = count(*)
        from tempdb.sys.columns sc
        where object_id = object_id('tempdb.dbo.' + @datatable);
 
        select @AutoFilterXML = N'<autoFilter ref="A1:'
            + rtrim(case when @colcount > 26 then char(64 + ((@colcount -1) / 26)) + char(65 + ((@colcount -1) % 26)) else char(64 + @colcount) end) + cast(@rowcount as nvarchar)
            + '" xr:uid="{' + cast(newid() as nvarchar(36)) + '}"/>';
    end;
 
    set @worksheet_xml = cast(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?><worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision"><sheetData>' + @RowDataXML + '</sheetData>' + @AutoFilterXML + '</worksheet>'
    as varbinary(max));
 
    set @WorksheetFileName = 'sheet' + cast(@CurrentWorksheet as varchar) + '.xml';
    exec dbo.AddFileToArchive
        @FileName = @WorksheetFileName
        ,@FileContents = @worksheet_xml
        ,@ArchiveData = @WorkbookData output
        ,@ArchiveInfo = @ArchiveInfo output;
    set @CurrentWorksheet = @CurrentWorksheet +1;
 
    set @AutoFilterXML = N'';
end;
 
if @SelectOutput = 1
    select @WorkbookData as ExcelSpreadsheetData;
 
if @OutputFileName is not null and (select value_in_use from sys.configurations where name = 'Ole Automation Procedures') = 1
begin
    exec sp_oacreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken output;
    exec sp_oasetproperty @ObjectToken, 'type', 1;
    exec sp_oamethod @ObjectToken, 'open';
    exec sp_oamethod @ObjectToken, 'write', null, @WorkbookData;
    exec sp_oamethod @ObjectToken, 'savetofile', null, @OutputFileName, 2;
    exec sp_oamethod @ObjectToken, 'close';
    exec sp_oadestroy @ObjectToken;
end;
 
return;
GO
```

Example usage:

```
select * into #systables from sys.tables;
select * into #syscolumns from sys.columns;
select * into #systypes from sys.types;

exec dbo.GetExcelSpreadsheetData
    @Worksheets = 'sys.tables/#systables/autofilter|sys.columns/#syscolumns/autofilter|sys.types/#systypes'
    ,@OutputFileName = 'c:\tmp\ExcelData.xlsx';

drop table #systables;
drop table #syscolumns;
drop table #systypes;
```

Edit:
I agree with anyone who comments that this is a ridiculous thing to do in TSQL. It seemed like a bad idea at the time however it does make my life easier.