# Is it possible to return query results as an Excel/CSV file formatted as a BLOB or base64 encoded string?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Limitations on some software I'm using require me to think outside the box, so can you have a query that automatically returns a "file" with the results in it? I imagine it would be as BLOB or a base 64 encoded string or something similar.

Using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: That would depend, at least in part, on what database you are using and how you are accessing it.

Comment: @ScottHunter Updated description and tags. Microsoft SQL Server is what I'm using and I'm hitting the DB through a third party program that lets me execute raw SQL. Unfortunately this third party program has issues processing more than 1000 rows so I was looking for other ways of returning the data

Comment: You could use [`FOR XML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) or [`FOR JSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to squeeze the result in a XML or JSON respectively. Or simply use another client without such limits...

Comment: You can master a request which produces XML formatted for EXCEL,  OOXML.

Comment: @stickybit Thanks! I wish I could use something else, trust me...

Comment: @Serg Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use two methods to achieve this

**1. Use SQLcmd**

```
SQLCMD -S SERVERNAME -E -Q "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable"
-s "," -o "D:\MyData.csv"
```

Run this above command in a cmd and achieve the expected result.

**2. Use OpenRawset**

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=D:\;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited','SELECT * FROM [FileName.csv]')
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM DatabaseName
```

You need to have the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider available. The Jet 4.0 provider will work, too, but it's ancient, so I used this one instead.

### limitations:

The .CSV file will have to exist already. If you're using headers (HDR=YES), make sure the first line of the .CSV file is a delimited list of all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create objects in the target database or another database on the same server, you could use the stored procedures and functions from my answer to this question: [SSMS: Automatically save multiple result sets from same SQL script into separate tabs in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65081428/ssms-automatically-save-multiple-result-sets-from-same-sql-script-into-separate/65081823#65081823)

You would just need to exclude the @OutputFileName parameter to force output as a single column, single row varbinary(max).

```
select * into #systables from sys.tables;
select * into #syscolumns from sys.columns;
select * into #systypes from sys.types;

exec dbo.GetExcelSpreadsheetData
    @Worksheets = 'sys.tables/#systables/autofilter|sys.columns/#syscolumns/autofilter|sys.types/#systypes'

drop table #systables;
drop table #syscolumns;
drop table #systypes;
```

Output (truncated):

```
ExcelSpreadsheetData
-------------------------------------
0x504B0304140000000800DB78295479400A1
```