# Undefined function: "'CRC64'."

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have been trying trying to create a table and use CRC64 function on my table using MS Notebook, but getting the error.
This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database

Any suggestions how to fix this ?

[image]

```
select
CONCAT_WS('|',date,fullvisitorid,visitid,'${hivevar:sourceIDSplit}','${hivevar:sourceSchemaID}') AS test_skey
,CRC64(CONCAT_WS('|',date,fullvisitorid,visitid,'${hivevar:sourceIDSplit}','${hivevar:sourceSchemaID}')) AS test_skey_bigint
,*
,'${batchrunID}' AS batchrun_date
,'${sourceID}' AS source_schema_id
from vw_wom_3;
```

Comment: there is no built in CRC hash function in sql server cloud nor on-premises .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does SQL Server CheckSum calculate a CRC? If not how can I get MS SQL to calculate a CRC on an arbitrary varchar column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331157/does-sql-server-checksum-calculate-a-crc-if-not-how-can-i-get-ms-sql-to-calcula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to repro the scenario and could fetch the same error for CRC64 using MS Notebook as well if I try it in SQL query editor. It seems to be working perfectly fine for CRC32 using Notebook or in SQL Query Editor.

Hence, Could not find any built-ins for the CRC Hash function in Azure SQL

**Using MS Notebook:**

[image]

**Using Azure SQL Query Editor:**

[image]

However, You can use any other programming language VB or [C#](http://datahashfunction.azurewebsites.net/1.6.1/html/b6d6ab4f-1cbd-a7a1-84c5-91ed74d81854.htm) to implement the same or to use Microsoft has made a tool called "File Checksum Integrity Verifier" available.

Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier Utility: [Available Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200728195620/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533).

It claims to run on Windows 2000, XP, and Server 2003, but I've tested it with Win7 64-bit and it generates CRC, so I assume it works on later Windows as well.